# Issues with the mysql query

Tags: mysql

i am trying to get the result from thquery, but i am getting error on the line 2, where i am using the cast function:

```
SELECT ticketstickets.`ID`, ticketsusers.`fname`, ticketsusers.`lname`, ticketstickets.`subject`, 
        ticketstickets.`created`, CAST(ticketstickets.modified AS VARCHAR(100)) as modified,
        ticketstickets.`priority`, ticketstickets.`status`, 
        ticketsdepartments.`name` FROM ticketsusers, ticketstickets 
        LEFT JOIN ticketsdepartments ON ticketstickets.`DEPARTMENT_ID`= ticketsdepartments.`ID` 
        WHERE ticketstickets.parent = 0 
        AND ticketstickets.by=ticketsusers.ID
```

> I tried with convert function too, but same error: [Err] 1064 - You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'VARCHAR(100)) as modified,
>               ticketstickets.`priority`, ticketstickets.`s' at line 2

Comment: Why are you trying to cast it like that, is there a specific reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cast-functions.html) that a value cannot be casted to `varchar(N)`. Instead you should cast to `char(N)` (so without "var").

Answer (score 1):

use that instead

```
    CAST(ticketstickets.modified AS CHAR(100))
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is in your `CAST` statement.

Refer this post to correct your query:

[How to use the CAST function correctly in a MySql SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989643/how-to-use-the-cast-function-correctly-in-a-mysql-select-statement)